# K Means Clustering - ID's instead of indices in R

Tags: r, k-means

I cluster product IDs on amount of sales and profit of sales to identify product IDs on which I need to focus more.

The code below takes column 2 (amount of sales) and column 3 (profit of sales) as input for kmeans. Instead of the current labeling, row 1 is product 1, row 2 is product 2, etc. I want the labels to be product IDs (which is data_nz[,1]) instead of row indices.

```
k2 <- kmeans(data_nz[,2:3], centers = 3, nstart = 1000)
```

When I output the data examples in my clusters (exclude cluster 2 because these are the ones I don't care about):

```
k2$cluster[k2$cluster != 2]
```

I get the row indices and the cluster number,  but what I want is the product ID and the cluster number.

[image]

Example of my dataset below: Product_ID, amount_of_sales, profit_of_sales

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please do not post your data as images.  No one wants to type it all in. Instead, please use `dput` to make a text version of your data and paste that into your question so that we can copy and paste into R.

Comment: Try `rownames(data_nz) <- data_nz[,1]` ?

Comment: @CoreyLevinson Thanks, your answer works as well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have an ordered vector of product IDs in `data_nz[, 1]`, which matches the vector with cluster number (`k2$cluster`). You can look at them side by side like this:

```
data.frame(product_id = data_nz[[1]],
           cluster = k2$cluster)
```

If you want to drop certain rows you can:

```
data.frame(product_id = data_nz[[1]],
           cluster = k2$cluster
           )[k2$cluster != 2, ]
```